# PHPMailer not setting charset in header correctly

Tags: character-encoding, phpmailer

Im using PHPMailer 6.1.8 for sending plain text mails. I want to send them with utf8 encoding but in Thunderbird the received eMails still have the wrong content type in header:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

My PHP code:

```
function sendMail($subject, $body, $to, $from = 'mail@server1.intranet.lan', array $cc = [], array $bcc = []) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->charSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->setLanguage = 'de';

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = '****';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = '****';
    $mail->Password = '****';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    
    $mail->setFrom($from);
    $mail->addAddress($to);

    foreach ($cc as $address) {
        $mail->addCC($address);
    }

    foreach ($bcc as $address) {
        $mail->addBCC($address);
    }

    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $mail->Body = $body;

    $mail->send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is case-sensitive for property names, so change this:

```
$mail->charSet = 'UTF-8';
```

to

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

You might consider this as a hint to get a decent IDE, since any good one would have flagged this without you even running the code.

Comment: Im using Komodo Edit 11.1. But it doesn't flagged this. You have advices for good IDE?

Comment: IMHO the best at the moment is JetBrains PHPStorm, but Microsoft VSCode (or the open derivative VSCodium) is also very good. Make sure you install static analysis plugins like phpcs, psalm, phpstan, and "Php Inspections ​(EA Extended)"; they will work wonders on your code quality.